# Easier way to SSH to prevent typing both hostname and username?

Tags: linux, unix

I remotely connect to a computer for work using SSH and I was wondering if there was an easier way to connect. Every time I enter

```
ssh hostname -l username
```

Hostname and username is very long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alter the ~/.ssh/config file on unix or linux systems. You can do:

```
vi ~/.ssh./config
```

Which will bring you to the file. Then type *i* (for insert) and enter:

```
Host nickname_to_give
         HostName the_hostname
         User your_username
```

Press esc to get out of the insert and type *:wq* to save and quit. To ssh using the nickname, type the command:

```
ssh nickname_to_give
```